# How to select only one checkbox from list of checkboxes with help of javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have html form with lots of checkboxes which are dynamically generated by PHP based on data in my mysql table. First 3 checkboxes (FBS, PPBS, RBS) are such that only one should be selected. if checkbox 1 is selected then 2 and 3 must be deselected, if 2 is selected then 1 and 3 must be deselected, if 3 is selected then 1 and 2 must be deselected. so essentially either none of the first 3 checkboxes should be selected or only one.

i cant use radio button as these checkboxes are dynamically generated. if i use radio button then there will be issue with rest of the checkboxes.
sample code is given below.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="boxset[]" value="FBS" id="1">&nbsp;FBS<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="boxset[]" value="PPBS (2 hrs)" id="2">&nbsp;PPBS (2 hrs)<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="boxset[]" value="RBS" id="3">&nbsp;RBS<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="boxset[]" value="SGOT" id="4">&nbsp;SGOT<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="boxset[]" value="SGPT" id="5">&nbsp;SGPT<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="boxset[]" value="ALP" id="6">&nbsp;ALP<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="boxset[]" value="T. Protein" id="7">&nbsp;T. Protein<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="boxset[]" value="S. Albumin" id="8">&nbsp;S. Albumin<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="boxset[]" value="T. Bilirubin" id="9">&nbsp;T. Bilirubin<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="boxset[]" value="D. Bilirubin" id="10">&nbsp;D. Bilirubin<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="boxset[]" value="Urea" id="11">&nbsp;Urea<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="boxset[]" value="Creatinine" id="12">&nbsp;Creatinine<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="boxset[]" value="Sodium (Na+)" id="13">&nbsp;Sodium (Na+)<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="boxset[]" value="Potassium (K+)" id="14">&nbsp;Potassium (K+)<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="boxset[]" value="Chloride (Cl-)" id="15">&nbsp;Chloride (Cl-)<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="boxset[]" value="Calcium" id="16">&nbsp;Calcium<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="boxset[]" value="Phosphorous" id="17">&nbsp;Phosphorous<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="boxset[]" value="Uric Acid" id="18">&nbsp;Uric Acid<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="boxset[]" value="CPK" id="19">&nbsp;CPK<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="boxset[]" value="CPK-MB" id="20">&nbsp;CPK-MB<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="boxset[]" value="Cholesterol" id="21">&nbsp;Cholesterol<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="boxset[]" value="Triglyceride" id="22">&nbsp;Triglyceride<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="boxset[]" value="HDL" id="23">&nbsp;HDL<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="boxset[]" value="LDL" id="24">&nbsp;LDL<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="boxset[]" value="Amylase" id="25">&nbsp;Amylase<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="boxset[]" value="Cholinesterase" id="26">&nbsp;Cholinesterase<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="boxset[]" value="LDH" id="27">&nbsp;LDH<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="boxset[]" value="T3-Total" id="28">&nbsp;T3-Total<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="boxset[]" value="T4-Total" id="29">&nbsp;T4-Total<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="boxset[]" value="TSH" id="30">&nbsp;TSH<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="boxset[]" value="Vitamin B12" id="31">&nbsp;Vitamin B12<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="boxset[]" value="25-OH-Vitamin D" id="32">&nbsp;25-OH-Vitamin D<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="boxset[]" value="FSH" id="33">&nbsp;FSH<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="boxset[]" value="LH" id="34">&nbsp;LH<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="boxset[]" value="Prolactin" id="35">&nbsp;Prolactin<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="boxset[]" value="HbA1c" id="36">&nbsp;HbA1c<br>
```

Comment: Why can't the first 3 be radio buttons and the rest checkboxes?

Comment: @Nick : cant keep radio buttons because (1)as these checkboxes are dynamically generated by PHP based on mysql database table. and once this form gets submitted it goes into different table of database. (2) if i keep radio button for first 3 and checkboxes for remaining then extra amount of php script required which makes code complicated. so if there is javascript solution for that i would like to do it

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of cake for you.

```js
$(function()
{   
    $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function()
    {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');

            if(id == 1)
            {
                $(":checkbox[id=2]").prop("checked",false);
                $(":checkbox[id=3]").prop("checked",false);
            }
            else if(id ==2)
            {
                $(":checkbox[id=1]").prop("checked",false);
                $(":checkbox[id=3]").prop("checked",false);
            }
             else if(id ==3)
            {
                $(":checkbox[id=2]").prop("checked",false);
                $(":checkbox[id=1]").prop("checked",false);
            }
            
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="boxset[]" value="FBS" id="1">&nbsp;FBS<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="boxset[]" value="PPBS (2 hrs)" id="2">&nbsp;PPBS (2 hrs)<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="boxset[]" value="RBS" id="3">&nbsp;RBS<br>
```

Comment: i really appreciate your efforts. but i need pure javascript solution as i never used jquery before

Answer (score 0):

Check this Out https://jsfiddle.net/shoesheill/x4j750ov/4/

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').off().on('click', function() {
   $('input[name="' + this.name + '"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```